# why i am getting this error i need to install android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, ubuntu-22.04, connection-refused

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 and java:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.10.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Why am I getting this error?

> cannot install "android-studio": Post
> https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: proxyconnect tcp: dial
> tcp:80: connect: connection refused

I tried:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

to get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best version to install is the one in the official website at https://developer.android.com/studio.

Follow the official installation instructions and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you I found a file to download and then unzip it and it also has a video to guide you though it's a little old but we can work it up